# Python : multiple values key in dictionnary to pair of key/value

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my input dictionary:

```
dict = {"key1": [value1, value2], "key2": ["value3", "value4", "value5"]}
```

I need the following result:

`[(key1, value1), (key1, value2), (key2, value3) ...]`

How can I do that in python?

I want to use this to create a table1 in order to join it to a table2 by "value".

Comment: Please show what you have tried based on your research around this task. What didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

Since you tag the `pandas`

```
s=pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack()
list(zip(s.index.get_level_values(0),s))
Out[869]: 
[('key1', 'value1'),
 ('key1', 'value2'),
 ('key2', 'value3'),
 ('key2', 'value4'),
 ('key2', 'value5')]
```

Comment: @jezrael I got you , this is slow

Comment: devilishly beautiful

Answer (score 1):

If you want an approach in pure Python:

```
[(k, inner) for k, v in dct.items() for inner in v]
```

```
[('key1', 'value1'),
 ('key1', 'value2'),
 ('key2', 'value3'),
 ('key2', 'value4'),
 ('key2', 'value5')]
```

I would recommend *not* using the name `dict` for a dictionary, as it overrides the builtin type constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First realize in Python alone (prior to version 3.6) dict's are not ordered. Hence the order in the resulting list of tuples will likely not be the same as the assignment to the dict.

Given that, you can do:

```
di={"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4", "value5"]}

result=[]
for k,li in di.items():
    for e in li:
        result.append((k,e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want something simple like this:

```
my_dict = {"key1": ["value1", "value2"], "key2": ["value3", "value4", "value5"]}

my_list = []

for my_key, value_list in my_dict.items():
    for value in value_list:
        my_list.append({my_key:value})

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key1': 'value2'}, {'key2': 'value3'}, {'key2': 'value4'},
 {'key2': 'value5'}]
```

I'm intentionally keeping it very basic.  Iterate your dictionary, iterate each list of values, build a dictionary, append that dictionary to a new list.  There are several ways to do this, this is simply one very readable/easy to understand option.

Answer (score 1):

Using *list comprehension*

```
l = [(i, j) for i in d for j in d[i]]    
# [('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2'), ('key2', 'value3'), ('key2', 'value4'), ('key2', 'value5')]
```